# Table sorter with delimiters rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, sorting, html-table, tablesorter

I have a table that has a column named Goal, that table gets filled with ruby like this:

```
<table  data-sorted="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th><a rel="tooltip" title="Name">Name</a></th>
      <th>subname</th>
      <th>Days</th>
      <th>%</th>
      <th>Goal</th>
      <th>achieved</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
<tbody>
 <% @results.each do |id, rows| %>
 <% rows.each do |row| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b><%= row[:name] %></b></td>
      <td><%= row[:subname] %></td>
      <td><%= row[:days] %></td>
      <td class="<%= status_indicator(row[:percentage].to_f) %>"><%= number_to_percentage(row[:percentage], :precision => 2)%></td>
      <td class="{sorter: 'thousands'}"="<%= row[:goal].to_i %>"><%=number_with_delimiter(row[:goal].to_i) %></td>
      <td class="achieved"><%= row[:achieved].to_i %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

according to my online research i have this on the jquery.

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
    // set a unique id 
    id: 'thousands',
    is: function(s) { 
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
        return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
    }, 
    format: function(s) {
        // format your data for normalization 
        return jQuery.tablesorter.formatFloat( s.replace(/,/g,'') );
    }, 
    // set type, either numeric or text 
    type: 'numeric' 
}); 

$(function() {
    $("[data-sorted=myTable]").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            6: {//zero-based column index
                sorter:'thousands'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

sorting works in all the columns of the table but on the ones that i have a thousand delimiter, i get this as a result

1. this is how the table starts on load

[image: this is how the table starts on load]

2. this is how the table renders when sorted

[image: this is how the table renders when sorted]

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459710/tablesorter-with-jquery-does-not-sort-numbers-correct

Comment: not really, the problem seems to be with the delimiters, since without them the sorter works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the headers option is assigning the "thousands" sorter to the 7th column (zero-based index)

```
headers: {
    6: {//zero-based column index
        sorter:'thousands'
    }
}
```

Where as the meta-data is assigning it to the 5th column

```
<td class="{sorter: 'thousands'}"...
```

So either you need to add the [meta-data plugin](https://github.com/jquery-orphans/jquery-metadata) to make the class name work, or change your header option to target the proper column:

```
headers: {
    4: {//zero-based column index
        sorter:'thousands'
    }
}
```