# Tablesorter sorting comma separated number columns incorrectly

Tags: jquery, sorting, tablesorter

First time working with jQuery:

I'm using tablesorter to sort my table. Its acting weird with sorting numbers. Here is an example of how its sorting in descending order:
[image]

Here is an example of how its sorting in ascending order
[image]

I tried a few things like adding the class "{sorter: 'digit'}" to the  element and adding [left padding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459710/jquery-tablesorter-is-not-sorting-number-correctly) but not sure why its happening like this. Another table in the project works perfectly fine with the tablesorter.

My code is as follows:

```
 $('#timeSeriesTable' + this.chartId).tablesorter({
    widgets: ["filter", "zebra"],
    widgetOptions: {
        // if true, a filter will be added to the top of each table column;
        // disabled by using -> headers: { 1: { filter: false } } OR add class="filter-false"
        // if you set this to false, make sure you perform a search using the second method below
        filter_columnFilters: true,

        // Hide filter boxes by default.
        filter_hideFilters: true,

        // Set this option to false to make the searches case sensitive
        filter_ignoreCase: true,

        // if true, search column content while the user types (with a delay)
        filter_liveSearch: true,

        // Use the $.tablesorter.storage utility to save the most recent filters (default setting is false)
        filter_saveFilters: false,

        // Delay in milliseconds before the filter widget starts searching; This option prevents searching for
        // every character while typing and should make searching large tables faster.
        filter_searchDelay: 300,

        // Applies style to columns
        zebra: ["normal-row", "alt-row"]
    },
    sortList: this.sortingList
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Update: I did figure out that the sorting is basically ignoring any number after comma. I saw a similar issue [here](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/issues/890) and tried to add a custom parser, but it still doesnt seem to work.

Steps taken:
 1. Add custom parser

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: "humanReadableNumber",
        is: function (s) {
          return /^[\d,]+$/.test(s);
        }, format: function (s) {
          return s.replace(/,/g, ''); 
        }, type: "numeric"
    });
```

2. Tell the header to use this parser:

   $("#timeSeriesTable0").tablesorter({headers: {1: {sorter: 'humanReadableNumber'}}});

It still doesn't work. Am I missing something here?

Example of a column sorted in ascending order, this clearly shows sorting is being done for digits before the comma in each number:

[image]

Comment: You may need a [custom parser](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html).

Comment: Would you please share an example of the HTML being used. I think the problem is the parser is trying to deal with both the `123` and `+123%` from the same cell; you might need to use `.split(" ")` inside the parser, or use a [`textExtraction` method](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#textextraction).

Comment: Hi Mottie, I think what it's doing is its clipping the numbers after first comma it encounters. I will add another screenshot of a sorted column to show the issue..

Comment: Modifying [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/) to show the problem would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this in case it helps anyone else:

I ended up adding a parser to deal with comma separated numbers and then adding it as a class to the `<td>` element.

Custom parser code:

```
  $.tablesorter.addParser({
        id: "commaSeparatedNumber",
        is: function (s) {
            return /^[0-9]?[0-9,\.]*$/.test(s);
        },
        format: function (s) {
            return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(s.replace(/,/g, ''));
        },
        type: "numeric"
  });
```

Here is the code for adding the above parser to my `<td>` element:

```
 td.addClass("sorter-commaSeparatedNumber");
```